# Is there any application like catia or at least able to open catpart

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any application like Catia or at least able to open catpart?
Was sombody able to install Catia on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice is [**OpenSCAD**](http://www.openscad.org/about.html), that focuses precisely on 3D modelling for industrial purposes:

> OpenSCAD is a software for creating solid 3D CAD models. It is free
>   software and available for Linux/UNIX, Windows and Mac OS X. Unlike
>   most free software for creating 3D models (such as Blender) it does
>   not focus on the artistic aspects of 3D modelling but instead on the
>   CAD aspects. Thus it might be the application you are looking for when
>   you are planning to create 3D models of machine parts [...].

Then you have a few commercial alternatives:

- [**BRL-CAD**](http://brlcad.org) - "a powerful cross-platform Open Source combinatorial Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG) solid modeling system that includes interactive 3D solid geometry editing".
- [**AutoQ3D**](http://www.autoq3d.com/) - a cross-platform 3D CAD conceived with beginners with mind.
- [**VariCAD**](http://www.varicad.com/en/home/) - "compact, fast, easy to use, and provides everything necessary for mechanical design".

Apart from these you may also check [**FreeCAD**](http://www.freecadweb.org/), a parametric 3D modeller; as I understand this philosophy has been loosing followers.

Regarding CATPart, there are very few programmes out there able to read it. And those that do apparently use libraries licenced for the purpose. You are advised to opt for a more portable format.